# How make chain of callbacks in android

Tags: java, android, callback, listener

I want to implement this scenario:

I have an ACTIVITY, one CLASS, and a SERVICE. 
What I want to do is making a chain of callbacks like this =>
ACTIVITY 《《 Class 《《 SERVICE
(Hint: create a callback in class to my activity  that it has another callback inside it that run for an event that happens in service)

I know how to make callback for the special event between to component, but I don't know how to do that for the above situation?

Note: I KNOW EVERYTHING ABOUT BROADCAST-RECEIVER FOR GETTING RESULT FROM SERVICE, I WANT TO DO IT BY CHAIN OF CALLBACKS!

Thanks for your time...

Comment: I feel assaulted by that all caps sentence.

Comment: @JClassic    I DID NOT HAVE "Intent to disrespect"    ;)   sorry.....

Answer (score 0):

You can register a callback to the service by aidl.
In activity class, you call call the register function, when service connection is connected.

below is the aidl code.

```
import com.xx.xx.aidl.IServiceCallback;

interface IMyService {
    void registerCallback(in IServiceCallback cb);
    void unregisterCallback(in IServiceCallback cb);
}



// IServiceCallback.aidl
package com.xx.xx.aidl;

interface IServiceCallback {
    void onConnected();
    void onDisconnected();
    void onError(int error);
}
```